# Problem with bootstrap 5 modal implementation

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

I have an ASP.NET CORE mvc project in which I call an API and show the data in a table including the raw data of players and two columns for update and delete. The problem is when I implement bootstrap modal for delete function, It shows the success result of `TempData`, But fails to complete the action and the player is still in the table!
Here is the delete action in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePlayer(int id)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/" + id);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                TempData["success"] = "Player Deleted Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("GetAllPlayers");
                
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

This is the view

```
    @model IEnumerable<Player>
@{
    ViewData["title"] = "All Players";
}
<style>
    .container {
        max-width: 95vw;
    }
</style>
<a asp-action="GetPlayer" class="btn btn-primary">Get Player</a>
<a asp-action="AddPlayer" class="btn btn-primary">Add Player</a>
<h2 class="h3 my-5 text-muted text-center fw-bold">A List of All Players</h2>
<div class="container" style="overflow:scroll">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-secondary text-white">
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Nationality</th>
                        <th>Update</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var player in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bg-dark text-white">@player.Id</td>
                            <td class="bg-warning">@player.Name</td>
                            <td class="bg-primary">@player.Position</td>
                            <td class="bg-info">@player.Nationality</td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="UpdatePlayer" asp-route-id="@player.Id">
                                    <i class="h3 bi bi-pencil-fill"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                               <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                               <i class="h3 bi bi-x-square-fill"></i>
                               </button>

                               <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                               <div class="modal-dialog">
                               <div class="modal-content">
                               <div class="modal-header">
                               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Player</h5>
                               <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                               </div>
                               <div class="modal-body">
                               Are you sure?
                               </div>
                               <div class="modal-footer">
                               <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DeletePlayer">
                               <a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                               <input type="hidden" value="@player.Id" name="id" />
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
                               </form>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               </div>


                            <td>
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First， check your database, whether the data has been deleted. Second , check your GetAllPlayers action , whether to load all the data again,  leading to the player is still in the table.

Comment: Already checked! It's still in the database. In a normal scenario and without modal with just a form with post method it works fine! The problem arises on modal implementation.

Comment: According to your code  <input type="hidden" value="@player.Id" name="id" />, when you post form you pass the id to action. Set a breakpoint to see if the id value is successfully passed to the DeletePlayer action.

Comment: Something strange happened! the value of id is not empty, But the id value of the actual player neither! It gets the first player in the table with lowest id value and deletes it!

Comment: Modal implementation is only for the first player not all of them! It's in foreach loop though

Comment: Changing name value to @player.Id, This time it passes value of zero for id!

Comment: Try the updated way in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242770/discussion-between-ahamad-zooghi-and-qing-guo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
<i class="h3 bi bi-x-square-fill"></i>
</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
```

`<button>` has an attribute like `data-bs-target` which defines the id of the modal that we want to open.
So, value for data-bs-target and id of the modal in `<div>` has to be the same.

You set `id="exampleModal"`for the first, so Modal implementation is only for the first player not all of them.

Try to change `data-bs-target="#@player.Id"`in the `<button>`  and the `id="@player.Id"`in above  `<div>`. Then  will redirect the application to delete action and delete a player.